# Link to a specific section of my app, or the app store if it hasn't been downloaded?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm in the process of updating my iOS app, and one feature that I'd love to add would be the ability to create links (to send via email, or for social media) that would allow users who have downloaded the app to be taken to a certain section of the app, and users who haven't to be taken to the app store page for my app. I also want it to take desktop users to the itunes page for my app.

Now, I've been looking into url schemes as I think this is the way forward, and have managed to create a custom url scheme that will indeed take users to different parts of my app. However, I'm struggling to find a way to check if the app has been installed, and what device the user is on etc.

Would I need to use a server to redirect them to the correct place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the best way to do it is with universal links, introduced in iOS 9.

https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9/